# GLSL - Cannot convert from "const highp 4-component vec4" to "default out highp 3-component vec3"

Tags: java, c++, opengl, glsl

I'm following in2gpu.com's tutorial on OpenGL and I'm stuck on the shader part. I've read around on forums on the error but I only find instances when people have used vec3's as vec4's hence the error but I don't think I've made that error, at least not what I've managed to see:

Vertex Shader:

```
#version 430

void main(void) {
    vec4 vertices[3];
    vertices[0] = vec4( 0.25, -0.25, 0.5, 1.0);
    vertices[1] = vec4(-0.25, -0.25, 0.5, 1.0);
    vertices[2] = vec4( 0.25, 0.25, 0.5, 1.0);

   gl_Position = vertices[gl_VertexID];
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
#version 430

out vec3 color;

void main(void) {
    color = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

Error:

```
Vertex shader failed to compile with the following errors:
ERROR: 0:6: error(#160) Cannot convert from: "const highp 4-component vector of vec4" to: "default out highp 3-component vector of vec3"
ERROR: error(#273) 1 compilation errors.  No code generated


Could not compile shader!
```

I've tried to convert the vertex data like this:

```
gl_Position = vec4(vertices[gl_VertexID]);
glPosition = vec3(vertices[glVertexID].xyz); (Incase gl_Position was actually a vec3)
```

but to no success.

Any help appreciated!

EDIT: Shader loader--

```
public class ShaderLoader {

public static int createShader(String vertexShaderSource, String fragmentShaderSource) {
    int vertex_shader = loadShader(vertexShaderSource, GL20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    int fragment_shader = loadShader(fragmentShaderSource, GL20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    int link_result = 0;

    int programID = GL20.glCreateProgram();
    GL20.glAttachShader(programID, vertex_shader);
    GL20.glAttachShader(programID, fragment_shader);

    GL20.glLinkProgram(programID);
    GL20.glValidateProgram(programID);
    GL20.glGetProgrami(programID, link_result);

    if(link_result == GL11.GL_FALSE) {
        System.out.println("Could not link program!");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    return programID;
}

public static int loadShader(String filename, int type) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src/shaders/" + filename));
        String line;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(line).append("\n");
        }
        reader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    int shaderID = GL20.glCreateShader(type);
    GL20.glShaderSource(shaderID, builder);
    GL20.glCompileShader(shaderID);
    if(GL20.glGetShaderi(shaderID, GL20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS) == GL11.GL_FALSE) {
        System.out.println(GL20.glGetShaderInfoLog(shaderID, 500));
        System.out.println("Could not compile shader!");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    return shaderID;
}
```

}

And in my main class I use this to initialize it:

```
int shaderProgram = ShaderLoader.createShader("vertexShader.txt", "fragmentShader.txt");
```

EDIT2:

To check if the shaders are swapped I added this into my`loadShader()`:

```
if(type == GL20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER) {
        System.out.println("Vertex: \n" + builder);
    } else if(type == GL20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER) {
        System.out.println("Fragment: \n" + builder);
    }
```

Output:

```
Vertex: 
#version 430

void main(void) {
    vec4 vertices[3];
    vertices[0] = vec4( 0.25, -0.25, 0.5, 1.0);
    vertices[1] = vec4(-0.25, -0.25, 0.5, 1.0);
    vertices[2] = vec4( 0.25, 0.25, 0.5, 1.0);

   gl_Position = vertices[gl_VertexID];
}

Fragment: 
#version 430

out vec4 color;

void main(void) {
    color = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: "*Vertex shader failed to compile*" I rather suspect you *also* have a bug in your shader loading code. Namely, you tried to compile your fragment shader as a vertex shader.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas Wow both of you were right, the compiler problem was solved by changing the color to a vec4 - and in my shader loader I tried to load both with with "GL_VERTEX_SHADER"! However the program wont link, I'll add my ShaderLoader class in an edit! Thank you so much so far!

Comment: @Rabbid76 Yes, I'll paste some debug into my question above in an edit.

Comment: If it doesn't link query the program info log and show us the error message. Also: `glValidateProgram` without checking the result is rather useless. I also doubt it does what you expect it to do: `glValidateProgram` tests whether a draw command with the current state would be possible. This would, for example, also state an error if a VAO is missing, bound samplers are not fitting the program and so on. It does **NOT** check if the program has compiled/linked successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `getProgrami()` function incorrectly. The second parameter is to tell the function which internal flag's value you want to return, in this case that would be `GL20.LINK_STATUS`. You would then assign the return value of this function to your `link_result` variable. So the line:

```
GL20.glGetProgrami(programID, link_result);
```

should be changed to this:

```
link_result = GL20.glGetProgrami(programID, GL20.LINK_STATUS);
```